# Pandas round method doesn't work on float32 columns

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point

I have this pandas serie with a float32 type. For a reason that I haven't been able to debug, applying `round` doesn't seem to have any effect on it.

```
(Pdb) df
0    359.500000
1    357.589996
2    342.250000
3    334.070007
Name: data, dtype: float32
(Pdb) df.round(2)
0    359.500000
1    357.589996
2    342.250000
3    334.070007
Name: data, dtype: float32
```

The only round which seems to work is `round(0)`.

If I change the type to float it works as expected, but I would like to understand why I need to change my dataset from float32 to float.

```
(Pdb) df.astype(float).round(2)
0    359.50
1    357.59
2    342.25
3    334.07
Name: data, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/50213). Casting to `float` works because it converts the column to `float64` for which `round` works correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I guess there's no plans of making sure it works on future updates ?